# How many nodes does a Web App in Azure has?

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I am enabling security service for my web app in Azure that indicates a price "per node". I don't see that information in the Web App console. I checked the app service plan used by the web app but that information is not there as well. Did I just miss it on those places or it's stored somewhere else? I already tried searching but using the keywords "node count web app in Azure" and variations of that don't produce desirable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/security-center/), you can find this:

> Each SQL Database server (logical server that may contain multiple SQL
>   databases and/or SQL Data Warehouse databases) counts as one node.

App service plan same as SQL Database server, so one app service plan counts as **one** node.

Comment: I was so consumed in the console that I forgot about the pricing page outside of it. Thank you Jason Ye!